# flink read data from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I write a simple example

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","xxxxxx")
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect","xxxxxx")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "caffrey")
val stream = env
  .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
.print()

env.execute("Flink Kafka Example")
```

when I run this code I got an **error** like this:

> [error] Class
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointNotifier not found
>   - continuing with a stub.

I google this error and find `CheckpointNotifier` is an `interface`.
I really don't understand where did I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `CheckpointNotifier` is a class from an older Flink version, I suspect that you are mixing different Flink dependencies in your pom file.

Make sure all Flink dependencies have the same version.

Comment: I change downgrade the flink version  and it works thanks!